# Simple smart contract in ethereum remix - ParserError: Expected ';'

Tags: node.js, ethereum, solidity, truffle, remix

I trying test some simple smart contract but don't know I have error
Can anybody tell me where I have a mistake?

I want to test this code but this error stops me.

```
interface IERC20Token {
    function balanceOf(address owner) public returns (uint256);
    function transfer(address to, uint256 amount) public returns (bool);
    function decimals() public returns (uint256);
}

contract TokenSale {
    IERC20Token public tokenContract = '0x12740510086c7062d5131BFe7C680c8b5D728c7f' // the token being sold
    uint256 public price = 1000000000000000;              // the price, in wei, per token
    address owner;

    uint256 public tokensSold;

    event Sold(address buyer, uint256 amount);

    function TokenSale(IERC20Token _tokenContract, uint256 _price) public {
        owner = msg.sender;
        tokenContract = _tokenContract;
        price = _price;
    }
```

SCREENSHOT
[image: REMIX SCREENSHOT]

Answer (score 1):

Line 10. Add a semicolon before your comment.

IERC20Token public tokenContract = '0x12740510086c7062d5131BFe7C680c8b5D728c7f'; // the token being sold

Comment: Nothing change a new errors - screenshot: [link](https://prnt.sc/10fioze)

Comment: It did in fact change, you have a new error; just in the same line. Read the bottom left of your screen. You are using outdated syntax when declaring `IERC20Token public tokenContract`.

Comment: I'm sorry friend, but stil don't know how to edit correctly. Please help me with line of code.